# Sending commands over Gmail

Tags: gmail, special-characters, copy-paste

Sometimes I send (and receive) long command lines to colleagues over Gmail. When the command spans many lines Gmail adds newline character making me unable to copy the command directly to the terminal.

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 3):

Why not just paste the command into a text file and attach it to the email?